# How to calculate the same item in a list tuple

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples, calculated-columns

I got a list tuple like this：

```
tup_list = [('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 21.325), ('UL00628', 6.675), ('UL00628', 22.5), ('UL00628', 5.5), ('UL00628', 15.525), ('UL00628', 12.475), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00428', 28.0), ('UL00428', 28.0), ('UL00428', 28.0), ('UL00428', 28.0), ('UL00428', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00428', 28.0), ('UL00428', 28.0), ('UL00428', 28.0), ('UL00428', 28.0), ('UL00428', 28.0), ('UL00428', 28.0), ('UL00428', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00628', 28.0), ('UL00428-OGA', 28.0)]
```

I want to calculate the same item in each tuples, like UL00628, UL00428?
What is the iteration can i use?

By the way, the tup_list comes from an excel file. The code is below:

```
load_all = dict()
file_name ='***.xls'
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('d:\**%s'%file_name)
table = wb.sheet_by_name('***')
date_start_month= int(input('Pls enter the date of start month:'))
date_start_day= int(input('Pls enter the date of start day:'))
date_end_month= int(input('Pls enter the date of end month:'))
date_end_day = int(input('Pls enter the date of end day:'))
count = 0
tup_list = list()
tup = tuple()
nrows = table.nrows
if table.cell(1, 11).value == '****':
    for num in range(2,nrows):
        date_of_load = table.cell(num,11).value #this is a date value
        #print(date_of_load)
        year,month,day,hous,minute,second = xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_tuple(date_of_load,0) # date is a tuple, (y,m,d,h,min,second) 
        if month in range(date_start_month,date_end_month+1) :# the month is OK?
            if day in range(date_start_day, date_end_day+1): # find the day
                grade_name = table.cell(num,3).value #grade
                grade_num = table.cell(num,5).value #quanlity
                tup = (grade_name, grade_num)
                tup_list.append(tup)
                count +=1
```

^^^^^^^^^
this is the original data

```
NO  Grade   quantity    Loadday
9   UL00628 28.0000     2018/2/7
10  UL00628 28.0000     2018/2/7
11  UL00628 28.0000     2018/2/7
12  EVA-OGC 28.0000     2018/2/7
13  EVA-OGC 28.0000     2018/2/7
14  UL00628 28.0000     2018/2/8
15  UL00628 28.0000     2018/2/8
16  UL00628 28.0000     2018/2/19
17  UL00628 28.0000     2018/2/19
18  UL00628 28.0000     2018/2/19
19  UL00628 28.0000     2018/2/19
20  UL00628 28.0000     2018/2/19
21  UL00628 28.0000     2018/2/19
22  UL00628 28.0000     2018/2/19
23  UL00628 28.0000     2018/2/19
24  UL00628 28.0000     2018/2/20
25  UL00628 28.0000     2018/2/20
26  UL00628 28.0000     2018/2/20
27  UL00628 28.0000     2018/2/20
28  UL00628 28.0000     2018/2/20
```

I need to find out the correct loadday and then get the grade and quantity and calculate each grade in total.

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate the same item in each tuples"? Count the occurence, sum their values, average them?

Comment: please mention sample output as well....

Comment: @MrT yes, that is what I want to do

Comment: @Narendra The output should like this: UL00628  526.00；UL00428 420.00.

Answer (score 0):

For data munging, especially involving Excel or CSV-files I would use `pandas` instead of directly `openpyxl`

Apart from that, once you have the list of tuples, you can use a `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
results = defaultdict(list)
for grade, quantity in tup_list:
    results[grade].append(quantity)
```

## Other problems

Other changes I would do would be to

- Put as much of the distinct parts of the program in separate functions
- Make sure the input gathering can handle when a non-`int` value is passed in,
- Put the inputs in a `dict`, so if one day you get the input for the data you need from another script, or portion of the program, you can easily reuse this
- Use generators as much as possible instead of functions returning lists
- Open resources using the `with` statement
- Use `pathlib.Path` for handling files and filenames
- Use `if __name__ == "__main__"`

test

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pathlib import Path 
import xlrd

def get_int_inputs(questions):
    for key, msg in questions.items():
        answer = None
        while not answer:
            try:
                answer = int(input(msg))
                yield key, answer
            except ValueError:
                pass


def parse_file(filename, inputs):
    with xlrd.open_workbook(filename) as wb:
        table = wb.sheet_by_name('***')
        if table.cell(1, 11).value == '****':
            for num in range(2,nrows):
                year, month, day, *_ = xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_tuple(date_of_load, 0)
                if not inputs['date_start_month'] < month <= inputs['date_end_month']:
                    continue
                if not inputs['date_start_day'] < day <= inputs['date_end_day']:
                    continue
                grade_name = table.cell(num,3).value
                grade_num = table.cell(num,5).value
                yield grade_name, grade_num


def aggregate(quantities):
    results = defaultdict(list)
    for grade_name, grade_num in quantities:
        results[grade_name].append(grade_num)
    return {grade_name: sum(val) for grade_name, val in results.items()}


if __name__ == '__main__':

    wanted_input = {
        'date_start_month': 'Pls enter the date of start month:',
        'date_start_day': 'Pls enter the date of start day:',
        'date_end_month': 'Pls enter the date of end month:',
        'date_end_day': 'Pls enter the date of end day:',
    }
    inputs = dict(get_int_inputs(wanted_input))

    filename = Path('D:/' , '***.xls')
    quantities = parse_file(filename, inputs)
    result = aggregate(quantities)
```

Without sample data, I can't test the code, so it might be full of bugs

## Pandas

Another approach is to use `pandas` to do the data handling

Then you would arrive at something like this

```
from pathlib import Path 
import pandas as pd

def parse_data(df, inputs):
    if df.columns[11] != '****':  # index might be different, depending on whether there is an index-col and 0- or 1-based indexing
        return None

    dates = df[<date_column_label>]   
    # or if it needs conversion to datetime
    # dates = pd.to_datetime(df[<date_column_label>])
    date_correct = dates.dt.month.between(
            inputs['date_start_month'], 
            inputs['date_end_month'] + 1, 
            inclusive = False,
            ) & dates.dt.day.between(
            inputs['date_start_day'], 
            inputs['date_end_day'] + 1, 
            inclusive = False,
            )
    return df[date_correct].groupby(<grade_name_label>)[<quantity_label>].sum()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wanted_input = {
        'date_start_month': 'Pls enter the date of start month:',
        'date_start_day': 'Pls enter the date of start day:',
        'date_end_month': 'Pls enter the date of end month:',
        'date_end_day': 'Pls enter the date of end day:',
    }
    inputs = dict(get_int_inputs(wanted_input))

    filename = Path('D:/' , '***.xls')
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name='', header=0)
    result = parse_data(df)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the details. When I ran the first code, the system report error:  File "test2.py", line 12
    yield key, answer
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I find out the problem. In" answer = int(input(msg) " there missed ')'. I still try to fix the error.

Comment: After I fixed this, there is another error :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 54, in <module>
    result = aggregate(quantities)
  File "test2.py", line 37, in aggregate
    for grade_name, grade_num in quantities:
  File "test2.py", line 25, in parse_file
    if not inputs['date_start_month'] < month <= inputs['date_end_month']:
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable

Comment: fixed that last one by changing `inputs = dict(get_int_inputs(wanted_input))`